# Batch operations in git client for Windows

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, client

Is there a git client for Windows that allows you to perform batch operations (commit, switch branch, pull, push, create tag) over a group of repositories?

**EDIT:**
There is an application with modular structure, having each module residing in a separate git repository, and quite often I need to perform the same operation, e.g. switch branch, simultaneously in all of those repositories or a bigger part of those. For instance, to make some change which won't be included in the main branch (but this change may affect multiple modules at once), deliver the code from this branch to the client, and then return to the main branch for all modules at once (without the custom change).

Moving over to use of submodules or subtrees, for various reasons, isn't currently an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need such a thing? Also, I should warn you that asking for off-site tools or software is off-topic. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question, to explain the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at 'repo':
https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-repo/